# Use JavaScript to stripslashes ? possible

Tags: php, ajax, stripslashes

I'm using ajax to grab a URL. The problem is the URL has slashes in it and when the JQuery load takes place afterwords it will not load the page.

AJAX success bit:

```
success: function(data) {
 $('#OPTcontentpanel').load(data.OPTpermalink);
```

PHP

```
echo json_encode( array('OPTpermalink'=>$OPTpermalink,));
```

AND the response

```
http:\/\/www.divethegap.com\/update\/options\/padi-open-water\/
```

So need to strip the slashes. I know how to do it in PHP but not in <del>AJAX</del> JavaScript.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 29):

A new answer to an old question:

```
String.prototype.stripSlashes = function(){
    return this.replace(/\\(.)/mg, "$1");
}
```

Example of use:

```
var str = "You\'re slashed \/\\..\/\\"; // Text from server
str = str.stripSlashes() ;
```

output:

```
You're slashed /\../\
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an old post but thought I would add my answer, seems more efficient than some other answers here:

```
var url = "http:\/\/www.divethegap.com\/update\/options\/padi-open-water\/"

var res = url.replace(new RegExp("\\\\", "g"), "");
```

This will replace all occurrences of a backslash character with nothing.

Answer (score 6):

There has been a good port of many of php's core functions, including `stripslashes` over here: http://phpjs.org/functions/stripslashes/

```
function stripslashes (str) {
  // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   improved by: Ates Goral (http://magnetiq.com)
  // +      fixed by: Mick@el
  // +   improved by: marrtins
  // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // +   improved by: rezna
  // +   input by: Rick Waldron
  // +   reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +   input by: Brant Messenger (http://www.brantmessenger.com/)
  // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // *     example 1: stripslashes('Kevin\'s code');
  // *     returns 1: "Kevin's code"
  // *     example 2: stripslashes('Kevin\\\'s code');
  // *     returns 2: "Kevin\'s code"
  return (str + '').replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
    switch (n1) {
    case '\\':
      return '\\';
    case '0':
      return '\u0000';
    case '':
      return '';
    default:
      return n1;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're sending JSON, but inserting it directly into a HTML element. That is not wise, can create broken results, and probably not what you want to do in the first place.

You should probably either

- change the PHP script's output to create proper HTML
- expect JSON on the JavaScript side (using jQuery's `dataType` parameter, or the shorthand [`$.json()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), and parse that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried string.replace?

```
success: function(data) {
 $('#OPTcontentpanel').load(data.OPTpermalink.replace("\\", ""));
```

Comment: There are string that will not work with simple replace (in case there are \ at the string or double \)